# Building 64-bit MIPS Big endian cross-compiler toolchain

Tags: gcc, mips, cross-compiling, mips64, linux-toolchain

I am trying to build a 64-bit MIPS big endian cross-compiler toolchain. I have been using the following guide (substituting aarch64 for mips64):
https://preshing.com/20141119/how-to-build-a-gcc-cross-compiler/

I have used the following versions of each library mentioned in the guide:

- binutils-2.31.tar.gz
- gcc-7.3.0.tar.gz
- linux-4.18.tar.gz
- gmp-6.1.2.tar.xz
- mpc-1.1.0.tar.gz
- mpfr-4.0.1.tar.gz
- isl-0.18.tar.bz2
- cloog-0.18.1.tar.gz

I have successfully built the toolchain, yet it is producing the following binary:

ELF 32-bit MSB executable, MIPS, N32 MIPS64 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib32/ld-uClibc.so.0, with debug_info, not stripped

However, what I need is the following:

ELF 64-bit MSB executable, MIPS, MIPS64 rel2 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld.so.1, for GNU/Linux 2.6.12, stripped

Does anyone know what step I am doing incorrectly that is preventing the appropriate binary being built?